# Create export script in Hybris which to export all products that exist in Online catalog but not in Staged

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm new to Hybris. That's what I've come up with so far:

```
$version=Online      

"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""Product.csv"" );"

insert_update Product ; catalog(id [allownull=true] ; catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true] ; code[unique=true,allownull=true] ; name

"#% impex.exportItems(""SELECT {P:pk} FROM {Product as P}, {CatalogVersion as CV}, {Catalog as C} WHERE {P:catalogversion}={CV:PK} AND {CV:catalog}={C:PK} AND {C:id}='$catalog' AND {CV:version}='$version'"", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1 );"
```

Looks OK, but it won't work. I'd appreciate ur help

Comment: Does it give some sort of error message? What does it do?

Comment: What exactly you mean by `export all products that exist in Online catalog but not in Staged`. Do you want to exports only online catalog products? or the difference?

Comment: only the online catalog

Answer (score 1):

`$catalog` is not defined, you have just defined the version.

Answer (score 0):

select {p.pk} from {genericvariantproduct as p join catalogVersion as cv on {p.catalog}={}